# Xamarin Android build issue in Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin

I've been trying to download Xamarin for my visual studio 2015, but it won't download. My internet is working fine, and I've tried downloading in different browsers, but nothing happens. I'm in Zimbabwe. I don't know whether this is affected by my region or what.... Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried downloading/installing Xamarin via modifying you Visual Studio installation to include Xamarin?

Comment: What did you try already? I don't believe there are region locks. What is your error message, what link did you use?